# How to configure my hosting provider for email when DNS redirection already in place?

Tags: email, dns, gmail, redirection, hosting

First of all I apologize for my poor understanding of network and I hope I used the correct terminology for everything:

I have bought a domain name with 1&1 to create an online shop, using kingeshop. I followed the steps explains [here](http://www.kingeshop.com/How-can-I-have-my-own-domain-name-bbebafaaaaaa.asp) to point the domain name to kingeshop IP address and everything is working fine.

Now I would also like to use my domain name to create an email account. But 1&1 seems to say they're not responsible for this now the DNS is transfered to kingeshop's. What I'm wondering is who is really "in charge" of my domain name now?

1&1 also lets me configure the MX-record but I don't have a clue what I can do with this. Could I just use an existing gmail address somehow?

Thanks a lot for any help or clarity you can bring me on that matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For email to work, you need to add `MX Records` in a zone file of Domain's Authoritative Nameservers. Look-up your domain at who.is to find your nameservers. If they are *.1and1..., then you'll need to add MX records at 1and1 control panel. If nameservers belong to kingeshop, add MX records at their control panel.

If you've followed the instructions of the link you provided in question, you're using 1and1 nameservers. So, setup MX records in 1and1 control panel.

Now the question is: What're the MX Records I need to enter if I want to use domain for email (as seems from question)?
Answer: Ask your mail server administrator.

If you don't have access to any mail server, its better to use free edition of Google Apps (Its free for upto 10 users). Follow [this link](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) & click Get Started button. Follow instructions to sign up. After you'll get to Control Panel of Google Apps, click `Setup` on top nav bar. Again follow instructions & you'll get [Google's MX records](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33915) which you can enter at control panel of 1and (or, wherever your authoritative nameservers are).

Answer (score 0):

The MX record should point to the SMTP server of the company hosting your email. The company doing the mail hosting will provide this information to you. Note that you cannot point the MX record to an arbitrary SMTP server, since the server must be configured to accept email for your domain.

Comment: So I can't just use smtp.gmail.com can I? Is registering with Google App the answer?

Comment: @Johann No. smtp.gmail.com isn't MX record of Google's mail servers. SMTP is a mail service which wouldn't work if MX record hasn't been configured correctly. See my answer.